# How to save as into a customized destination on macOS?

Tags: mac, finder, macos

When I try to saveAs a file on macOS (like in a browser such as Safari or Chrome), the only destinations I see are "devices", "favorites" or "recent places". However, how to save in a different location?

Is there a short key to go inside folders? Or what is the trick?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so we see what you see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the Save As sheet is in, for the lack of the proper term, compact view. To expand the sheet click the down arrow to the right of the Save As: text box (Export As: in Safari)

[image: Save As Sheet Compact View]

- Clicking the down arrow, the one the red arrow is pointing to, opens up the sheet showing additional controls, as in the image below

[image: Save As Sheet Expanded View]

Comment: You might want to add that, once in the file picker, you can drag any visible Finder window into it to automatically go there [which saves all that Windows-style fiddling about in an extended hierarchy every time.]

Comment: @Tetsujin, Feel free to make improvements to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I use Cmd-Shift-G often in these situations.
Works in any file dialog or Finder window.
This allows you to type in any custom path, or better yet, cut/copy/paste any custom path.
It also keeps track of any recent paths you used.
[image]